# Testing Stripe checkout using Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, stripe-payments

Is there any way to test stripe checkout (since it is redirecting to stripe checkout page)
I got the following code:

```
cy.intercept(
        'GET',
        'https://checkout.stripe.com/pay',

        {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: {
                message: 'Request successful',
                result: ['my-data']
            },
        }
    ).as('getSession')
cy.get('#checkout-btn').click()
cy.wait('@getSession').then((interception) => console.log(interception))
```

I can see, that it is printing the interception in the console, but immediately after that, it's redirecting to a new page, where I can see the body. How should I stop that redirection so I can somehow get a successful test?

Comment: Can you try adding `followRedirect: false` and check.

Comment: I add it, but it appears it is only for requests ( So nothing happen)

Comment: What are you trying to validate after `cy.get('#checkout-btn').click()` ?

Comment: If it did not redirect I can validate the status, body even just ( cy.wait('@getSession') will be enough ), but it is redirecting to a new page, where you cant do anything ....

Comment: Currently testing Checkout using a full page redirect with Cypress is not supported as far as I know, but it is something that is on the radar. If you would like to write to support and document the testing use case your feedback will be noted.

Comment: Can you use [stripe-mock](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-mock) to create a mock server?